# Restrict spaces and accept only Latina letters

Tags: regex, yup

I'm new to regexp. I'm trying to figure out how to allow only Latin letters, prohibit spaces, but so that my other regexps still work.

I have 6 steps for password. 4/6 I already covered. But have problems with the remaining 2 steps.

```
matches(/^(?=.*[a-z])/, "mustContainsLowerCase") works
matches(/^(?=.*[A-Z])/, "mustContainsUpperCase") works
matches(/^(?=.*\d)/, "mustContainsNumber") works
matches(/[^\dA-Za-z]/, "mustContainsSpecialCharacter") works

matches(/^(?=.* )/, "Should not contains spaces "), <- Not working
matches(/??/, "must contains only Latin letters"), <- I have no ideas 


const valid = "a1W@";
const invalid1 = "a1W@ a1W@";
const invalid2 = "a1W@法" (法 forbidden, only Latin letters allow)
```

I will be grateful for any help, as I have no ideas left.

Comment: `^(?=.* )` *requires* a space, you need a negative lookahead, `^(?!.* )` / `^(?!\S*\s)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will appreciate it if you give me some ideas about the last step.

Comment: I suspect you want to allow only ASCII letters, so you want to error out on any non-ASCII letter, right? Try `/^(?!.*[^\P{Alphabetic}a-zA-Z])/u`

Comment: It works, thanks. Could you please write the answer below so that I mark it as an "answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^(?=.* )` regex *requires* at least one regular space in the string since `(?=...)` is a *positive* lookahead. You need a *negative* lookahead here, `^(?!.* )`. Alternatively, `/^(?!\S*\s)/` can be used to disallow any whitespace in the string.

To disallow any non-ASCII letter inside a string, you can use the ECMAScript 2018+ compliant pattern like

```js
/^(?!.*[^\P{Alphabetic}a-zA-Z])/u
```

Here, `[^\P{Alphabetic}a-zA-Z]` defines any Unicode letter that does not fall into the `A-Z` and `a-z` ranges.